# Jar to include to use javax.annotation.*

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3, jdeveloper

I'm a bit confused. I need to compile a project in jDeveloper 11.1.1.6.0. The server side of the project is deployed on the Glassfish server. On the machine of the project's creator everything compiles without any problems.

Using project `properties -> Libraries and Classpath` I added the libraries such as `gf-client.jar`, security etc. from `$glassfish_home/glassfish/modules` and some others (e.g. `hibernate3.jar` from hibernate dir).

When I try to compile the project I receive the following errors:

> package javax.annotation.security does not exist

and

> package javax.persistence does not exist.

I suppose that I miss some jars to include. I tried to find which jars (from Glassfish or from JDK) contain `javax.annotation.*` and `javax.persistence.*` but I couldn't.

If you have any ideas I would be thankful!

Comment: Have you tried adding dependency on this artifact: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/6.0 ?

Comment: Thank you for reply, @PiotrNowicki! I downloaded `javaee-api-6.0.jar` and added it in the same way. I still get these error messages. Am I right if I say that the downloaded jar file contains only declarations of methods etc, but not implementation? Can it be the reason, because acoording to the page infrormation all packages I need are there.

Comment: These package / API is only for compilation - as you've said these are only interfaces / declarations - no implementation. The implementation will be available in the deployment environment. It's interesting why you're getting compile-time errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem and was able to solve it by adding a couple of dependencies to the Maven pom.xml file.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350852/1565374) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the source of the problem. The application consists of 2 projects, of which only one (mentioned in the question) uses EJB. I'm not sure if it is the way it should be, but I tried adding ejb-files to another project. And after `clean all` and `rebuild all` it compiled like a charm for me. I hope this will help somebody in the future.